# Cannot assign requested address using ServerSocket.socketBind

Tags: java, sockets, jvm, bind

When I'm trying to set up a socket server, I've got an error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: JVM_Bind
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:383)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:328)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:194)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:106)
    at socketyserver.SocketyServer.main(SocketyServer.java:12)
Java Result: 1
```

Whole code is simplest as it can be:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException
{
    ServerSocket serverSocket;
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9999);
}
```

I'm 100% sure that my ports are forwarded, Windows Firewall is off. Nothing blocks port 9999. What else can go wrong?

Comment: The javadoc of `BindException` states: Signals that an error occurred while attempting to bind a socket to a local address and port. Typically, the port is in use, or the requested local address could not be assigned. Are you certain you do not have your program running twice, where the first instance uses the port and the second instance throws the exception since the port is already in use by the first instance

Comment: Sounds like either another copy of your server is already running (double check task manager) or you just killed another version of the server and the socket is "lingering" for a while.

Comment: See http://nirlevy.blogspot.co.il/2007/12/tomcat-javanetbindexception-cannot.html "Cannot assign requested address" means that (in your case) it's probable that "localhost" does not map to a valid ip.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As other people have pointed out, it is most likely related to another process using port `9999`. On Windows, run the command:

```
netstat -a -n | grep "LIST"
```

And it should list anything there that's hogging the port. Of course you'll then have to go and manually kill those programs in Task Manager. If this still doesn't work, replace the line:

```
serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9999);
```

With:

```
InetAddress locIP = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.20");
serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9999, 0, locIP);
```

Of course replace `192.168.1.20` with your actual IP address, or use `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Thanks for anwsers, but before posting I've made sure that nothing blocks port 9999. After restarting my PC there's same error.

Comment: Yes. Everything that I run is automatically getting elevated privileges.

Comment: Yes, command line is running with administrator privileges. I'm using 

"java -jar SocketServer.jar" 

command.

Comment: Would someone explain, why the second form is different/better?

Comment: I was still getting this error; checked the code and realised my IP (the code was in a VM) had changed.

Comment: This is incorrect. If the port was taken by another process the error would be "java.net.BindException: Address already in use". The error "java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address" problem is because you've tried to open a socket on invalid IP address.

Comment: @dan.mwasuser2321368 You're close. It would be 'port already in use'.

Comment: @EJP With java version "1.8.0_141" at least, the exception thrown is "java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)"

Comment: @EJP Which was also the case when I tested this under Java 7 before posting my comment last year.

Answer (score 37):

It may be related to a **misconfiguration** in your `/etc/hosts`.
In my case, it was like this:
`192.168.1.11 localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1 localhost`

Comment: adding this configuration in hosts file saved my day 127.0.0.1 localhost . Thanks!

Comment: I have `127.0.0.1 localhost` in /etc/hosts, yet I am still getting the error (macOS Monterey).

Answer (score 16):

Just for others who may look at this answer in the hope of solving a similar problem, I got a similar message because my ip address changed.

```
java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:126)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.open(SelectChannelConnector.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.doStart(SelectChannelConnector.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
```

Comment: it was the same for me aswell. ipadress was changed.

Comment: thank you, I would have tried to figure this out for years had I not read this.

Comment: for me the issue was that previous ip address was still in etc/hosts

Answer (score 15):

The error says `Cannot assign requested address`. This means that you need to use the correct address for one of your network interfaces or `0.0.0.0` to accept connections from all interfaces.

The other solutions about ports only work after sometimes-failing black magic (like working after some computer restarts but not others) because the port is completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 8):

Java documentation for `java.net.BindExcpetion`,

> Signals that an error occurred while attempting to bind a socket to a
>   local address and port. Typically, the **port is in use**, or the
>   **requested local address could not be assigned**.

Cause:

The error is due to the second condition mentioned above. When you start a server(Tomcat,Jetty etc) it listens to a port and bind a socket to an address and port. In Windows and Linux the hostname is resolved to IP address from `/etc/hosts` This host to IP address mapping file can be found at `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`. If this mapping is changed and the host name cannot be resolved to the IP address you get the error message.

Solution:

Edit the hosts file and correct the mapping for hostname and IP using admin privileges.

eg:

```
#127.0.0.1 localhost
192.168.52.1 localhost
```

Read more: [java.net.BindException : cannot assign requested address.](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2014/02/fixing-javanetbindexception-cannot-assign-requested-address-JVMbind.html)

Comment: This is a different error than what the question was about.

Comment: The question was about an error message "Cannot assign requested address".  That error message is NOT the same as the error message your answer illustrates, or solves.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. 'Cannot assign requested address error' is due to to the OS being unable to resolve the 'localhost', which is required to start and shutdown the server. This is most commonly caused by a  wrongly configured hosts file. This error is  NOT particularly due to port being in use. I commented all the entries except this '127.0.0.1 localhost' from my /etc/hosts file to resolve similar issue w/ my tomcat app.

Comment: This solution is not correct. `localhost` must map to `127.0.0.1, and the 'real' IP address must map to a hostname other than `localhost`.

Answer (score 7):

if your are using server, there's "public network IP" and "internal network IP".
Use the "internal network IP" in your file /etc/hosts and "public network IP" in your code.
if you use "public network IP" in your file /etc/hosts then you will get this error.

Answer (score 4):

For me it was because a previous jmeter.properties change was still in play

```
httpclient.localaddress=12.34.56.78
```

Answer (score 1):

My laptop has an internal DNS name in the network, it was fine until *something* and then has broken.

To fix i added a line to route all requests by DNS name to my 127.0.0.1, my `/etc/hosts` looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       host.docker.internal
127.0.0.1       my-url.box #added for the problem
```

Might be relevant for someone.

It is easy to debug, just run a class until this is green:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new ServerSocket(0, 1, InetAddress.getLocalHost());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case:
Just **restarted my computer** and everything works fine after that.

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, it can't bind - which typically means it's in use by another process.  From a command line run:

> netstat -a -n -o

Interrogate the output for port 9999 in use in the left hand column.

For more information: http://www.zdnetasia.com/see-what-process-is-using-a-tcp-port-62047950.htm

Comment: As the error states, the address isn't available, which means the ports are completely irrelevant.

Comment: This is incorrect. If the port was taken by another process the error would be "java.net.BindException: Address already in use". The error "java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address" problem is because you've tried to open a socket on invalid IP address.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, delete from /etc/hosts

- 127.0.0.1 localhost
- 192.168.100.20 localhost <<<<---- (delete or comment)

Answer (score 0):

I came across this error when copying configurations from one server to another.

I had the old host's hostname in my **${JETTY_BASE}/start.ini jetty.host** property. Setting the correct jetty.host property value solved the issue for me.

Hope this helps someone in the future who has to work on multiple servers at once.

Answer (score 0):

if you happened on CentOS?

You should try to this.

$ service network restart

or

reboot your server.

Answer (score -1):

The port is taken by another process. Possibly an unterminated older run of your program. Make sure your program has exited cleanly or kill it.

Comment: It's not possible! I've just restarted my PC, it doesn't help.

Comment: This is incorrect.  If the port was taken by another process the error would be "java.net.BindException: Address already in use".  The error "java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address" problem is because you've tried to open a socket on invalid IP address.

Answer (score -2):

> java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address

According to `BindException` documentation, it basically:

> Signals that an error occurred while attempting to bind a socket to a local address and port. Typically, the port is in use, or the requested local address could not be assigned.

So try the following command:

```
sudo lsof -i:8983
```

to double check if any application is using the same port and kill it.

If that's not the case, make sure that your IP address to which you're trying to bind is correct (it's correctly assigned to your network interface).

Comment: This is incorrect. If the port was taken by another process the error would be "java.net.BindException: Address already in use". The error "java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address" problem is because you've tried to open a socket on invalid IP address.

Comment: @dan.mwasuser2321368 Thanks for the suggestion, I've improved my answer, please check my edit.