# Cannot assign requested address while trying to run a Java server through an ant script

Tags: java, linux, java-server

I have to execute a compiled Java server through an ant task for an assignment so that I can build a client for it. 
I don't have the code of the server but it's supposed to run on the 8181 port of the localhost after being launched. It's working in windows and on other linux machines but I cannot run on this one (crunchbang).
This is the error I get:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 second
root@drne:/home/wallen/uni/workspace/A5# ant run-server
Buildfile: /home/wallen/uni/workspace/A5/build.xml

setseed:

run-server:
     [java] Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.ServerRtException: Server Runtime Error: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
     [java]     at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.ServerMgr.createContext(ServerMgr.java:102)
     [java]     at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.HttpEndpoint.publish(HttpEndpoint.java:63)
     [java]     at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:171)
     [java]     at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createAndPublishEndpoint(ProviderImpl.java:113)
     [java]     at javax.xml.ws.Endpoint.publish(Endpoint.java:240)
     [java]     at it.polito.dp2.PJS.lab5.PJSInfoServer.main(Unknown Source)
     [java] Caused by: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
     [java]     at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
     [java]     at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:344)
     [java]     at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:336)
     [java]     at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:199)
     [java]     at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
     [java]     at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl.<init>(ServerImpl.java:98)
     [java]     at sun.net.httpserver.HttpServerImpl.<init>(HttpServerImpl.java:50)
     [java]     at sun.net.httpserver.DefaultHttpServerProvider.createHttpServer(DefaultHttpServerProvider.java:35)
     [java]     at com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer.create(HttpServer.java:129)
     [java]     at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.ServerMgr.createContext(ServerMgr.java:84)
     [java]     ... 5 more
     [java] Java Result: 1
```

Things I've tried:

- checking if there is another server running on that port
- running it as su

Comment: Please show us some code.

Comment: I only have the .class file of the server since the assignment is about writing a client that's compatible with the server we've been provided with. I can assume that the server code is working properly and that it should bind to localhost:8181 after being executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix what was giving me this error and as I supposed at the beginning of the matter it was not related to any java code: my loopback interface was weirdly down. 
`ifconfig lo up` did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8965155/cannot-assign-requested-address-jvm-bind) suggest that this may happen if the name "localhost" is not resolvable to an IP address. Check your `/etc/hosts` file and ensure that it has a mapping for `localhost` to the address `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Sadly that's not the case, the hosts file is correctly mapping localhost to 127.0.0.1. I also tried to comment the entries related to IPV6 address mappings thinking that they could arise issues but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you double check the server address you are deploying to. I had a misspelling on the server address and I got the exact same error...

I'm using the included web service libraries available in Java 6 & 7:

```
Endpoint.publish("http://myservername.com/myapi", new ServiceHandler(appSettings));
```

Double check the value for "myservername.com", this one is assuming port 80.
If you have some other port (i.e. 8080) then the command would look like this:

```
Endpoint.publish("http://yourservername.com:8080/myapi", new ServiceHandler(appSettings));
```

Hope that helps.