# Netbeans can't start derby server

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-7, derby

I've been trying to start the server but I get this error message:

> 2013-01-23 19:24:18.133 GMT : Security manager installed using the
>   Basic server security policy. 2013-01-23 19:24:18.430 GMT : Could not
>   listen on port 1527 on host localhost:  java.net.BindException: Cannot
>   assign requested address: JVM_Bind

On top of that I get a prompt saying:

> Unable to connect. Cannot establish a connection to
>   jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sample using
>   org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver (java.net.SocketException : Error
>   connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Network is
>   unreachable: connect.).

How is one suppose to fix such an issue?

Comment: Don't you have something else running on the 1527 port ?

Comment: This question might help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8965155/422353

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but my problem was I had my loopback (lo) network interface disabled... took me quite long to discover... (But most common would be another instance of derby already running I think)