# Unable to connect server java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: bind

Tags: java, java-7

Working fine when i connect the localhost(127.0.0.1), but unable to connect when i connect to 12.11.123.121. Getting below error.

Note: Given Socket server is dummy one.
**Error**

```
java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.channels.AsynchronousServerSocketChannel.bind(Unknown Source)
    at com.epro.welcome.ComputerInstruClient.serverStart(ComputerInstruClient.java:40)
    at com.epro.welcome.ComputerInstruClient.access$0(ComputerInstruClient.java:36)
    at com.epro.welcome.ComputerInstruClient$1.run(ComputerInstruClient.java:70)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**Code**

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.nio.channels.AsynchronousServerSocketChannel;
import java.nio.channels.AsynchronousSocketChannel;
import java.nio.channels.Channels;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class Test {
  private static void clientStart() {
    try {
      InetSocketAddress  hostAddress = new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName("12.11.123.121"),
          2583);
      AsynchronousSocketChannel clientSocketChannel = AsynchronousSocketChannel
          .open();
      Future<Void> connectFuture = clientSocketChannel.connect(hostAddress);
      connectFuture.get(); // Wait until connection is done.
      OutputStream os = Channels.newOutputStream(clientSocketChannel);
      ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(os);
      for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        oos.writeObject("Look at me " + i);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
      }
      oos.writeObject("EOF");
      oos.close();
      clientSocketChannel.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }

  private static void serverStart() {
    try {
      InetSocketAddress  hostAddress = new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName("12.11.123.121"),
          2583);
      AsynchronousServerSocketChannel serverSocketChannel = AsynchronousServerSocketChannel
          .open().bind(hostAddress);
      Future<AsynchronousSocketChannel> serverFuture = serverSocketChannel
          .accept();
      final AsynchronousSocketChannel clientSocket = serverFuture.get();
      if ((clientSocket != null) && (clientSocket.isOpen())) {
        InputStream connectionInputStream = Channels
            .newInputStream(clientSocket);
        ObjectInputStream ois = null;
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(connectionInputStream);
        while (true) {
          Object object = ois.readObject();
          if (object.equals("EOF")) {
            clientSocket.close();
            break;
          }
          System.out.println("Received :" + object);
        }
        ois.close();
        connectionInputStream.close();
      }

    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    Thread serverThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        serverStart();
      }
    });
    serverThread.start();
    Thread clientThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        clientStart();
      }
    });
    clientThread.start();
 }

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot assign requested address: JVM\_Bind](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8965155/cannot-assign-requested-address-jvm-bind)

Comment: Have you checked if the port is free?

Comment: this same port working fine in new socket() function. but unable to connect in asynsocketchannel

Comment: @Rhand please carefully read this thread. this is asynchronoussocketchannel, that is normal socket connection. please read thread carefully. Thanks for your information.

Comment: I have tried your code on my machine and no issues (with localhost and external ip). And found no issues, so I assumed there was an issue with the port (you did not mention checking this). Did you check the ip?

Comment: @Rhand then how system allow me to connect with simple  server = new Socket(host, port); function.

Comment: Why are you using Async channels when you don't use them asynchronously?