# Node.js Agent pools my requests

Tags: node.js, jmeter, agent

I am using node v0.10.12 . I am testing the server performance with the software Jmeter, which simulates that many users access the server. The problem is that when I simulate more the 10 users, the node.js pools my requests, because they are coming from the some host.

On the web is suggested to set:

```
http.globalAgent.maxSockets = 99;
```

But it doesn't work, because the agent continues to pool the requests if they are more then 10.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Also there is decision for JMeter.

You can run your script from different IP addresses (you can use [IP aliasing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_aliasing)). 
In HTTP Request sampler use property: Source IP Address (in the right bottom corner). You can set IP here. 
To specify different IP you should add [CSV Data Set Config](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65138-using-csv-data-set-config)  and enumerate list of IP in CSV file.

Comment: If JMeter sends requests with different ip address, how could packets come back(from the server to the JMeter client)?

Comment: Do you know why I receive this error?
`java.net.BindException: Can't assign requested address`

Comment: May be [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8965155/cannot-assign-requested-address-jvm-bind) will help you

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [hyperquest](https://github.com/substack/hyperquest) README, which is both funny and informative regarding this issue.