# Raspberry PI & Tomcat

Tags: java, linux, tomcat

I need help setting up my Tomcat server on my Rasp. The majo problem is, i can run Tomcat from its directory with startup.sh. It than says that tomcat is running ... what a lie. If i test it with  configtest.sh i get a few exceptions thrown at me.

further when i look @ catalina.out i get somthing like this:

```
23-Nov-2015 17:11:52.997 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.start$
23-Nov-2015 17:11:52.999 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.start$
23-Nov-2015 17:11:53.201 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.start$
23-Nov-2015 17:11:53.204 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.start$
23-Nov-2015 17:11:55.521 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.start$
23-Nov-2015 17:11:55.523 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.start$
23-Nov-2015 17:11:55.642 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.start$
23-Nov-2015 17:11:55.680 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start S$
23-Nov-2015 17:11:55.735 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start S$
23-Nov-2015 17:11:55.740 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start$
23-Nov-2015 17:11:55.751 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.$
 java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:3$
        at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:42$
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:713)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:659)
```

I'm not able to understand the error... There is nothing else running, i rebootet several times, checkt the processes, checked the ports but nothing is in use as far as i can see it.

I tried tomcat per apt-get as a service and as a simple package from tomcats website. Both without any sucess.

I than deletet all and installed apache just for testeng. Apache runs without any errors and is accesable via the browser after installation.

I got two questions.
1: What is the problem with tomcat? Any suggestions why tomcat may not be able to get a adress.

2: The main reson i want tomcat is to run a RESTFUL webaplication on the Rasp.Is there maby a other Webserver that can hold on to Java servlets or war files?

Setup: Raspberry PI2
Java 1.8
Tomcat 7 or 8 tried them both.

thanks in advance and a nice Monday too you

Comment: change the used port and try again, it seems the port you are trying to run it on is used by another service

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756039/how-to-change-the-port-of-tomcat-from-8080-to-80

Comment: i tryed using a difrent port .... :   23-Nov-2015 17:41:36.248 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.$
 java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:3$
        at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:42$
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:713)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot assign requested address: JVM\_Bind](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8965155/cannot-assign-requested-address-jvm-bind)

Comment: try to connect to it via: ip:port

Comment: @nafas ... nice idea... how should i connect to a server wich is not running ?

Comment: as I said, 99% something else is running, just try to c what you get, it'll give u some ideas

Comment: If the port is already in use then the networking stack will report that specifically. This is a generic failure to bind, which would make me suspect the OS is actively blocking the attempt. A firewall maybe?

Comment: I ám quite sure there is nothing runing in the background : pi@pi200 ~ $ netstat -a -n | grep "LIST"
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     5734     /var/run/avahi-daemon/socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8042     /var/run/dhcpcd.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8044     /var/run/dhcpcd.unpriv.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     6535     /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     1264     /run/udev/control