# Cannot assign requested address: JVM_Bind exception occurs for remote machines

Tags: java, jvm, serversocket

I tried to check whether a port is free in a remote machine by trying to create a ServerSocket with port and IP address of the machine. IP is accessible from my machine. but it produces an Exception "Cannot assign requested address: JVM_Bind".
I have seen many questions posted for this exception but does not answer for other than localhost.

my code is

```
  try {
                sock = hostName == null ? new ServerSocket(port) : new ServerSocket(port, 0, InetAddress.getByName(hostName));
                return true;
            } catch (Exception var14) {
                flag= false;
            } finally {
                if (sock != null) {
                    try {
                        sock.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
```

hostname - IP adress,
port      - port number

Comment: Have you seen this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8965155/cannot-assign-requested-address-jvm-bind) post?

Comment: yes, my code is the same as the code mentioned.

Comment: You cannot open server sockets on remote machines. You can only open sockets on your own machine (although, if your machine has several IP addresses, you can open a server socket only on one of those IP address)

Comment: how do I check if the port is free in remote machine ? or is it possible to check whether a port is free on a remote machine?

Comment: Why do you want to check if a port is free on a remote machine?