# tomcat error: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address (Bind failed)

Tags: java, tomcat, bind

Unable to resolve this error, i tried changing the shutdown port first, it didn't work, then i changed connector port too still it didn't work.

```
24-Nov-2020 16:44:39.487 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/manager] has finished in [69] ms
24-Nov-2020 16:44:39.498 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8088"]
24-Nov-2020 16:44:39.524 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
24-Nov-2020 16:44:39.566 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [7,031] milliseconds
24-Nov-2020 16:44:49.713 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await Failed to create server shutdown socket on address [localhost] and port [8012] (base port [8012] and offset [0])
    java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address (Bind failed)
        at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:436)
        at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:381)
        at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:584)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:721)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:667)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:344)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:475)
24-Nov-2020 16:44:49.732 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8088"]
24-Nov-2020 16:44:51.740 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
24-Nov-2020 16:44:53.745 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Stopping service [Catalina]
24-Nov-2020 16:44:53.939 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8088"]
24-Nov-2020 16:44:53.960 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
24-Nov-2020 16:44:53.967 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8088"]
24-Nov-2020 16:44:53.980 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8965155/cannot-assign-requested-address-using-serversocket-socketbind

Answer (score 0):

Looks like another application is already listening on that port.

If you are in Linux try to run this command to find out:

```
netstat -tulpen|grep 8012
```