# Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop'; Unable to start embedded Tomcat server - spring-boot-starter-web

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, nic

Spring application using Maven including only Spring Web dependency gives "Unable to start embedded Tomcat serve" error.

The same project runs on other computers like expected.

Spring Boot Version: 2.4.3 
Package Type: JAR 
Java Version: 11

No additional code added from the starter project except to print to the console for testing.

- Application runs and prints to the console like expected when tomcat is excluded int the pom.xml.
- Tested multiple ports.
- Tested JDK 8 and 11.

pom.xml dependancies:

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Log:

```
2021-02-22 16:17:28.896  INFO 34556 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication using Java 11.0.10 on Soul with PID 34556 (C:\Users\ryne0\Desktop\FullStackWeb\Spring\demo\target\classes started by ryne0 in C:\Users\ryne0\Desktop\FullStackWeb\Spring\demo)
2021-02-22 16:17:28.900  INFO 34556 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-02-22 16:17:28.902 DEBUG 34556 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Loading source class com.example.demo.DemoApplication
2021-02-22 16:17:28.995 DEBUG 34556 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@457c9034
2021-02-22 16:17:30.317 DEBUG 34556 --- [           main] .s.b.w.e.t.TomcatServletWebServerFactory : Code archive: C:\Users\ryne0\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.4.3\spring-boot-2.4.3.jar
2021-02-22 16:17:30.318 DEBUG 34556 --- [           main] .s.b.w.e.t.TomcatServletWebServerFactory : Code archive: C:\Users\ryne0\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.4.3\spring-boot-2.4.3.jar
2021-02-22 16:17:30.318 DEBUG 34556 --- [           main] .s.b.w.e.t.TomcatServletWebServerFactory : None of the document roots [src/main/webapp, public, static] point to a directory and will be ignored.
2021-02-22 16:17:30.353  INFO 34556 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 81 (http)
2021-02-22 16:17:30.374  INFO 34556 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-02-22 16:17:30.387  INFO 34556 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.43]
2021-02-22 16:17:30.507  INFO 34556 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-02-22 16:17:30.507 DEBUG 34556 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Published root WebApplicationContext as ServletContext attribute with name [org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT]
2021-02-22 16:17:30.508  INFO 34556 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1513 ms
2021-02-22 16:17:30.535 DEBUG 34556 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.s.ServletContextInitializerBeans : Mapping filters: characterEncodingFilter urls=[/*] order=-2147483648, formContentFilter urls=[/*] order=-9900, requestContextFilter urls=[/*] order=-105
2021-02-22 16:17:30.547 DEBUG 34556 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.s.ServletContextInitializerBeans : Mapping servlets: dispatcherServlet urls=[/]
2021-02-22 16:17:30.599 DEBUG 34556 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.s.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Filter 'requestContextFilter' configured for use
2021-02-22 16:17:30.600 DEBUG 34556 --- [           main] s.b.w.s.f.OrderedCharacterEncodingFilter : Filter 'characterEncodingFilter' configured for use
2021-02-22 16:17:30.600 DEBUG 34556 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.s.f.OrderedFormContentFilter     : Filter 'formContentFilter' configured for use
2021-02-22 16:17:30.817  INFO 34556 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2021-02-22 16:17:30.828 DEBUG 34556 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : ControllerAdvice beans: 0 @ModelAttribute, 0 @InitBinder, 1 RequestBodyAdvice, 1 ResponseBodyAdvice
2021-02-22 16:17:30.949 DEBUG 34556 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : 2 mappings in 'requestMappingHandlerMapping'
2021-02-22 16:17:30.991 DEBUG 34556 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Patterns [/webjars/**, /**] in 'resourceHandlerMapping'
2021-02-22 16:17:31.003 DEBUG 34556 --- [           main] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : ControllerAdvice beans: 0 @ExceptionHandler, 1 ResponseBodyAdvice
2021-02-22 16:17:31.104  WARN 34556 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop'; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
2021-02-22 16:17:31.110  INFO 34556 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2021-02-22 16:17:31.122  INFO 34556 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2021-02-22 16:17:31.197 DEBUG 34556 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 



2021-02-22 16:17:32.117 ERROR 34556 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop'; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:181) ~[spring-context-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356) ~[spring-context-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
        at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:155) ~[spring-context-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:123) ~[spring-context-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:934) ~[spring-context-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:585) ~[spring-context-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1311) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1300) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
        at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:229) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.WebServerStartStopLifecycle.start(WebServerStartStopLifecycle.java:43) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-context-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
        ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: standardService.connector.startFailed
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:244) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatWebServer.java:282) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:213) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
        ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1074) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
        ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to establish loopback connection
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:94) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:61) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl.<init>(PipeImpl.java:171) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SelectorProviderImpl.openPipe(SelectorProviderImpl.java:50) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.nio.channels.Pipe.open(Pipe.java:155) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.<init>(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:142) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorProvider.openSelector(WindowsSelectorProvider.java:44) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.nio.channels.Selector.open(Selector.java:295) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector(NioSelectorPool.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.close(NioSelectorPool.java:119) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.unbind(NioEndpoint.java:386) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1279) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:608) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1071) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
        ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: connect
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:476) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:468) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:694) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(SocketChannel.java:194) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer$LoopbackConnector.run(PipeImpl.java:127) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:76) ~[na:na]
        ... 36 common frames omitted
```

Comment: maybe this answer to a similar question should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18007598/10263562

Comment: Thanks for this, but the problem came from a network interface controller getting in the way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There was control software installed for the individuals Network interface controller (NIC) that allowed both ethernet and wifi to be used simultaneously. This was installed to supposedly improve gaming experience, but did not play nicely with tomcat in Spring. Once disabled the application was able to run as expected.

Edit:

A similar error occurs if your address or port is incorrect / already used. This fixes the error in most situations, but a driver like the one mentioned above may cause the error.

Comment: Hello, do you have the name of it or the service related to it?

Comment: This was a network interface Carr driver for an installed card. It will be different depending on card and driver installed - You can look at your drivers by looking at the Device Manager on windows.

Comment: @Callanbr My app also tell that the port is already in use but when I run  netstat -ano | findstr :[port] there's nothing run on that port. So this also must be the issue you've mentioned above right?

Answer (score 1):

It got fixed for me after changing server.port to 8080 from 80.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to run spring boot on my local network and that error occurred.
The problem was a **wrongly specified IP address property** inside my application-dev.yml file.

```
server:
  address: 192.168.0.107 // it needed to be 192.168.0.104
  port: 8080
```

**You can always check your IPv4 Address** by running **`ipconfig`**.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the `Gamingservices` service or go to the task manager and end the task of gamingservices and run again the application. or restart the computer.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when the port on which you are trying to start your TomCat server is already busy.
Among the above options described by other people, I also want to note that it may be that you have started your server from:

1. Another copy of idea
2. Or launched it from an artifact, it started up quietly and you didn't understand it)

And this copy of the server running on the same port prevents the current server from starting. I've had similar stupid mistakes with both options.